# How can I create certification_name and degree_school?

Tags: linkedin-api

I would like to fullfill the certification form.
I have this url from linkedin : https://www.linkedin.com/profile/add?startTask=CERTIFICATION_NAME and I would like to create my own "certification_name" but I don't know how to do that. It's the same problem with degree_school.
Can you help me please ?

Comment: same ask :( Hope someone can help